# How can i write a middleware logic for a module that exports multiple functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.0, es6-modules

I have a module that exports few functions. I want to write a middleware for the module. So, when any exported function from that module is called, i want middleware to first execute and decide whether or not intended function should execute.
I am using typescript and thought of exporting modules that execute same methods like this:

```
export {
foo: middleware
bar: middleware
baz: middleware
}
```

Which might not be the correct way of writing middlewares. Can you suggest the better approach?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to explicitly wrap your functions. In ES6 (should be directly portable to Typescript):

```
export default {
    foo: wrapMiddleware(fooMiddleware),
    bar: wrapMiddleware(barMiddleware)
}
```

`wrapMiddleware()` would look like this:

```
function wrapMiddleware(originalFunc) {
    return function(...args) {
        // Example:
        if (condition) {
            return originalFunc(...args)
        } else {
            return null
        }
    }
}
```

You can do this programmatically as well. For example:

```
let exports = { foo, bar }

for (let key in exports) {
    exports[key] = wrapMiddleware(exports[key])
}
```

Comment: If i have 10 or more methods to export, do you think writing middleware for all like this is better approach?

Comment: I think this is the cleaner way, even if it leads to some code that looks the same. If you align the code vertically (putting all calls to `wrapMiddleware` on the same column), it kinda looks like a table and it's easy to read. However, it can be done programmatically, I'll edit the question above

Comment: This is good. But i have to export the functions from namespace. Is there any other solution to export the object from namespace?

Answer (score 0):

expanding on @slezica answer. es6 exports are static, so you can't really be very creative about how you export your dependencies and the need to be listed on creation time. if you use commonJS you can export objects which will give you more flexibility about how things are exported, and you can do things like(ignore the functional approach, is just coding style. this can be made in a multitude of ways).

```

```
import * as fns1 from functions;
import * as fns2 from functions;
import toPairs from 'lodash/toPairs';
import fromPairs from 'lodash/fromPairs';
import map from 'lodash/map';
import flowRight from 'lodash/flowRight';
import curryRight from 'lodash/curryRight';

const applyMiddlewareToModule = module => (
  flowRight( // lodash's version of compose
    fromPairs, // convert back to object
    // maps the function from fn to middleware wrapped fn
    curryRight((map)(([fnName, fn]) => [fnNane, wrapMiddleware(fn)])), 
    toPair // convert the provided object to an array of [key, value]
  )
)

module.exports = {
  ...applyMiddlewareToModule(fns1),
  ...applyMiddlewareToModule(fns2)
}
```

```

but if you stick to es6 modules you can't so you have to wrap them before export 1 by 1